# 5th order polynomials that are solvable?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

I know a 5th order polynomial can't be solved in general using a finite combination of +, -, *, /, and roots. I can think of three types of 5th order polynomials with closed form roots. They are:

- (linear polynomial)*(quartic polynomial)
- (quadratic polynomial)*(cubic polynomial)
- $a*x^5+b$

Are there any other cases that are solvable? If there are I would like to get some understanding of them, but I am not familiar with Galois theory.

Comment: [This article](https://site.uvm.edu/ddummit/files/2021/04/Solving_Solvable_Quintics__Math_Comp_57_no195_1991__pp_387_401.pdf) is relevant. Mathematics of Computation, Volume 57, Number 195, July 1991, pp. 387-401

Comment: Actually, *every* non-constant polynomial with real coefficients can be written as a product of linear and quadratic polynomials (again, with real coefficients).

Comment: de Moivre's quintic is analogous to reduced cubic.

Comment: For example, $x^5+15x+12$ is irreducible, but has a solvable Galois group, namely the Frobenius group $F_{20}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Does that not hold for complex polynomials as well? The fundamental theorem of algebra guarantees roots, and the factor theorem guarantees linear polynomial factors...

Comment: Yes, in $\Bbb C[x]$ every polynomial can be written as a product of linear factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algebraic functions considered in [Ritt 1922] give i.a. the solvable quintics.

$a,b,c,d\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$

For the beginning, we get i. a. the following quintics from Ritt's paper.

$$a(z+b)^5+c=0$$

$$16a(bz+c)^5-20a(bz+c)^3+5abz+5a+d=0$$
$\ $

[[Ritt 1922] Ritt, J. F.: On algebraic functions which can be expressed in terms of radicals. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 24 (1922) (1) 21-30](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1922-024-01/S0002-9947-1922-1501211-X/)